# WooCommerce plaintext mail doesn't display currency symbol

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

WooCommerce order mails are not displaying currency symbol when plain text is set as the email type.
My settings are following.

```
Language Japanese
Currency Japanese yen 
WooCommerce Ver. 4.4.1
WordPress 5.5.1
Theme: StoreFront
```

If I change the currency to another one, for example 'Australian dollar', the dollar sign is added to the prices.
Or when I set HTML mail as the email type, yen symbol is added to prices without problem.

I also tried this changing the language settings to English, but it didn't work anyway.
I'd like to know why and if there is the way to fix this.

Mail example in Japanese (I want the yen symbol to be added to the prices)

```
小計:      188
送料:      1,390 送料として
決済方法:    銀行振込
合計金額:    1,577 0
```

Mail example in English

```
Subtotal:        188
Shipping:        1,390 via shipping
Payment method:  credit card (Stripe)
Total:   1,578
```

Answer (score 1):

Before a plain text email is sent in WooCommerce, all HTML tags and some HTML entities are stripped. Specifically, WooCommerce uses `wp_strip_all_tags` and `preg_replace` with a custom set of patterns and replacements to perform this operation.
You can inspect the code in `get_content` in `includes/emails/class-wc-emails.php`.

It appears that in this `preg_replace` operation, WooCommerce removes the HTML entity `&yen;` (¥) and thus, you are not seeing the currency in your plain text emails.
Note that `$plain_replace` includes the actual symbol for $ and £ and thus these currencies will not be removed.

Unfortunately, neither the pattern nor the replacement (`$plain_search` and `$plain_replace`) can be extended via a filter and thus your only option to exclude `&yen;` from being replaced would be to change the code inside the plugin. However, these changes will be overwritten whenever you update WooCommerce.

The most viable solution to exclude your currency symbol from being removed from the email content before the email is sent would be to overwrite your currency symbol in `get_woocommerce_currency_symbols` in `includes/wc-core-functions.php` using the filter `woocommerce_currency_symbols`.
In your case, you would replace `&yen;` with `YEN`.

However, this symbol is also used in all places where the currency symbol is displayed in the shop (e.g. cart, checkout, product page, etc.). That is, your website will display YEN instead of ¥ in all these elements.

This would be the most reasonable approach in my opinion for all currencies that don't use a special symbol for their code (e.g. AMD, EGP, CHF, ...).

In your specific case, where the "letter code" should only be used in the emails, I recommend extending / overwriting the WooCommerce email templates instead.
You should be able to do this without overwriting the actual email templates (and thus preserving upwards compatibility and after-update-issues down the line) by replacing the hooked actions with your custom actions (for instance `woocommerce_email_order_details` in `customer-on-hold-order.php`).

Comment: Hi how to write japanese yen symbol into this file :customer-on-hold-order.php?

Comment: I want to add ¥ into customer-on-hold-order.php how to do it?